# Expect Bad Request with Spring 6.1

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot-test, mockmvc

I used to have this test that worked as expected:

```
mvc.perform(get(ENDPOINT)
   .queryParam("myparam", "100")
   andExpectAll(
      status().isBadRequest().
      content().contentType(APPLICATION_PROBLEM_JSON),
      //language=json
      content().json("""
                    {
                      "type": "/problems/validation-error",
                      "title": "The request parameters didn't validate",
                      "instance": "my-endpoint",
                      "status": 400,
                      "errors": [
                        {
                          "path":"myparam","message":"size must be between 0 and 10"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                    """, true));
```

My API definition has the following parameter annotated:
`@RequestParam(required = false) @Size(max = 10)`

However this does not work anymore after upgrading from Spring Boot 3.1.8 to Spring Boot 3.2.3 that comes with Spring 6.1.4.
Now instead of being able to capture the request status, there's an exception thrown:

```
org.springframework.web.method.annotation.HandlerMethodValidationException: 400 BAD_REQUEST "Validation failure"
    at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.HandlerMethodValidator.applyArgumentValidation(HandlerMethodValidator.java:106)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:188)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:920)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:830)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1089)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:903)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:527)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at org.springframework.test.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet.service(TestDispatcherServlet.java:72)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:614)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain$ServletFilterProxy.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:165)
    at org.springframework.mock.web.MockFilterChain.doFilter(MockFilterChain.java:132)  at org.springframework.web.method.annotation.HandlerMethodValidator.applyArgumentValidation(HandlerMethodValidator.java:106)
```

What's the quickest and nicest way to have this test working again? I could write an AdviceTrait for that exception but I doubt that's necessary any time one wants to check for a 400.

Comment: You upgraded from what to what? Also please add the full stacktrace.

Comment: I've updated with more information. But please, be respectful though. It was not a random snippet but the most relevant part. I'm tired of contributors that post comments like yours trying to diminish the others. This kind of comments make stackoverflow less appealing to find support.

Comment: Generally the full stacktrace contains important information and the important information is generally not in the first part of the stacktrace. Hence the request, you also left out what you where upgrading which is crucial as well. So you are offended by the fact that someone wants to help you but ask for more information. Anyway there has been a change in validation of request parameters not needing an `@Validated` on the controller level anymore. Looks like you are running into that (but for that we would need the controller as well).